# Spring/Velocity/Maven/Tomcat - "requested resource is not available"

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven, velocity

I'm writing web application with using Spring, Velocity and Tomcat as container. My problem is that everything worked fine when I launched application on Windows 7, but some day I was forced to replace it with Windows 8. I've installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, m2e for Maven Integration, Velocity tools and Tomcat 7.x. When I started application, and typed "http://localhost:8080/web/hello" I've got `"HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available"` error. I have no idea what is going on, because it worked earlier. If it's needed I can paste some source code, but I think problem is with some wrong path after installing new Windows. Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your console log from the application startup. It probably shows you an error there and isn't starting up your application.

Otherwise it should you the log from Spring starting up successfully.

Comment: There is no errors in console log (I had one earlier, but was easy to fix).

Comment: Do you see the Spring startup log?

Comment: Check whether your tomcat is running. Have you checked the tomcat logs to see  whether the app is deployed correctly ? The log file is located in <apache-tomcat-dir>/logs/catalina.<date>.log. Check the latest entry in this log.

Comment: ->Udo : I can't see Spring startup log and I don't know how to show it.
->clinton : Latest entry in log is really old. I think it was when I just started/stopped Tomcat service to test installation. Later I created new Tomcat server in Eclipse and attached my application to it.

Comment: When you don't see the startup log from Spring then either the app isn't deployed, you misconfigured your logging or you are looking at the wrong spot.

Comment: -> Udo : You were right, I misconfigured my logging. Anyway when I've set up it, and added some notifications in source code, nothing showed up. Does it mean that my project is not deploying well? -> clinton : I've found log for my project (Before I was searching it in Apache Tomcat installation folder, not in workspace\metadata). And this is what I get when I want to show my hello page : "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Oct/2012:14:11:59 +0100] "GET /web/hello HTTP/1.1" 404 969"

Comment: If the spring startup log doesn't show up in your Eclipse console then something is wrong.

Comment: I solved the problem. Firstly I had Tomcat installed in "C:\Program Files\" folder. When I downloaded it in *.zip file,unpacked in "C:\" and set path to folder in eclipse, my application started. I don't know why installing it was a problem, because I've granted full control to my user on Apache Installation folder. Anyway thanks for help guys.

Comment: Sometimes you can get problems when you have got a space in your installation folder like "Program Files". If you can avoid it.